# Pycharm/Python OpenCV and CV2 importing error

Tags: python, opencv

Even after installing opencv using:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

I'm getting this error while importing it in pycharm

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cv2
```

I tried downloading it in differnt ways but it dosen't import

Comment: use the equivilent for python 3:

   "pip3 install opencv-python"

After running the appropriate pip command your package should be available to use from python.

Comment: how about upgrade your current pip library first? `!pip install --upgrade pip`. After that try this `pip install opencv-python --upgrade`

Comment: Show us the full output of this command `pip --version`

Comment: Tried all this, but still dosen't work

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem once when I used VS code. I tried to run the same code in PyCharm (with included opencv-python library) and it worked with no problems!

Comment: Its not runing in both pycharm and vs code